nano version 8 with "standard" keybindings for Ctrl-c, Ctrl-v,
Is it planned to make nano version 8 available in the Ubuntu 24.04 repository?
nano version 7.2 is part of Ubuntu 24.04.
nano version 8.0 and above supports the modern keybindings:
^Q quit, ^X cut, ^C copy, ^V paste, ^Z undo, ^Y redo, ^O open a file, ^W write a file, ^R replace, ^G find again, ^D find again backwards, ^A set the mark, ^T jump to a line, ^P show the position, and ^E execute.
I would like to use that keybindings as that is more familiar to me.

You can download it now from the Nano GNU homepage

nano text editor version 8 is built-in in Ubuntu 24.10 and later. nano version 8 is also available as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To learn more about this snap package run the following command:
snap info nano-strict

The results of snap info nano-strict include information about how to configure the nano snap package after installing it. This is NOT an official nano distribution; refer to the issue tracker for any problems regarding the use of this snap.
You can also download nano 8.2 from the official GNU nano homepage.
